# How to consume or Access Web API using Php?

Tags: php, api, asp.net-web-api

Hi Dears Friends i need your help.

How can we access Web api by using php??
i have doing like this but on Client_Id it shows me Access token Error while my Instagram Access token is fresh or not expired and correct

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['location'])){
    $maps_url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($_GET['lacation']);
$maps_json = file_get_contents($maps_url);
$maps_array=json_decode($maps_json,true);
   $lat= $maps_array['result'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng = $maps_array['result'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $instagram_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat='.$lat.'&lng'= .$lng. '&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

 $instagram_json = file_get_contents($instagram_url);
    $instagram_array = json_decode($instagram_json,true);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>WebApi_Learning</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="">
        <input type="text" name="location"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
    <?php 
    if(!empty($instagram_array)){
    foreach($instagram_array['data']as $image){
        echo '<img src='. $image['images']['low_resolution']['url'].'" alt="" />'; 
    }
    }
        ?>
               </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a comment but i cannot because of misssing reputations points. 
Looking at the API-docs, the media/search method   [API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) accepts these parameters:
lat, lng, access_token

Your $instagram_url totally misses the access_token but provides client_id instead which doesnt seem to be a valid input parameter for the media/search method.

My guess is you need to follow the authentification procedure in order to retrieve the access_token as described here [API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: Thanks Harry for You Help